# Matching both `[` and `]` inside square bracketed character set inside `sed`

Tags: bash, sed

I came across below statement [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005/27925):

> To include `]` in the list of characters matched by a bracket expression, make it the first character  (or first after `^` for a negated set): `[]abc]` or `[^]abc]` (not <strike>`[abc]]` nor `[abc\]]`</strike>).

So I tried out kind of below border case of matching and replacing both `[` and `]`:

```
echo '[]' | sed 's/[[]/^/'      #only [ in matching string (works)
echo '[]' | sed 's/[[]]/^/'     #both [] in matching string (fails #1)
echo '[]' | sed 's/[\[\]]/^/'   #escaping both [] in matching string (fails #2) 
echo '[]' | sed 's/[][]/^/'     #including ] as first character (as suggested by above quoted point) inside [..] leads to [][] pattern (fails #3)
echo '[]' | sed 's/[]]/^/'      #only ] in matching string (works)
```

Output was:

```
^]
^
^
^]
[^
```

In failures above, I felt it should have printed `^^`, that is, replacing both square brackets in `[]` with `^`. I have numbered failures `#1`, `#2` and `#3`.. Can someone please explain the reason behind the output I am getting in each of these failures and what should be the way to make it work when I want to match both `[` and `]`?

Comment: `echo '[]' | sed 's/[][]/^/g'` works. It says, do that substitution `g`lobally (otherwise, sed just does the first replacement on that line and stops trying.

Comment: Without the `g` flag, only the first match is replaced.

Comment: So `s/[][]/^/g` is the only correct one? Does it interprete first `[` and fourth `]` brackets for defining character set and 2nd `]` and 3rd `[` to be part of that character set? Also the output is still unchanged for failures `#1` and `#2`. Why we get this output for failures `#1` and `#2`

Comment: `<<<'[]' sed 's/[/X/'` will fail with `sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated s' command` where as `s/\[/X/` will return `X]`. `s/]/X/` will return `[X` thus `s/[[]]/X/` returns `X` because `[[]` matches `[` and `]` matches `]` thus the `[]` 2 characters  are replaced by `X`. Also `s/[][]/X/`will return `X]` whereas `s/[][]/X/2` returns `[X`. The gnu sed has a `--debug` option which may throw more light on the subject.